# Pandas plot: Assign Colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have many data frames that I am plotting for a presentation. These all have different columns, but all contain the same additional column `foobar`. At the moment, I am plotting these different data frames using

```
df.plot(secondary_y='foobar')
```

Unfortunately, since these data frames all have different additional columns with different ordering, the color of `foobar` is always different. This makes the presentation slides unnecessary complicated. I would like, throughout the different plots, assign that `foobar` is plotted bold and black.

Looking at [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), the only thing coming close appears to be the parameter `colormap` - I would need to ensure that the `x`th color in the color map is always black, where `x` is the order of `foobar` in the data frame. Seems to be more complicated than it should be, also this wouldn't make it bold.

Is there a (better) approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `matplotlib` directly rather than the dataframe plotting methods.  If `df.plot` returned the artists it added instead of an `Axes` object it wouldn't be too bad to change the color of the line after it was plotted.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def pandas_plot(ax, df, callout_key):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    ax : mpl.Axes
        The axes to draw to

    df : DataFrame
        Data to plot

    callout_key : str
        key to highlight

    """
    artists = {}

    x = df.index.values
    for k, v in df.iteritems():
        style_kwargs = {}
        if k == callout_key:
            style_kwargs['c'] = 'k'
            style_kwargs['lw'] = 2
        ln, = ax.plot(x, v.values, **style_kwargs)
        artists[k] = ln

    ax.legend()
    ax.set_xlim(np.min(x), np.max(x))

    return artists
```

Usage:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()

th = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1024)
df = pd.DataFrame({'cos': np.cos(th), 'sin': np.sin(th),
                  'foo': np.sin(th + 1), 'bar': np.cos(th +1)}, index=th)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'cos': -np.cos(th), 'sin': -np.sin(th)}, index=th)

pandas_plot(ax, df, 'sin')
pandas_plot(ax2, df2, 'sin')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could define a function which handles the special column in a separate `plot` call:

```
def emphasize_plot(ax, df, col, **emphargs):
    columns = [c for c in df.columns if c != col]
    df[columns].plot(ax=ax)
    df[col].plot(ax=ax, **emphargs)
```

---

Using code from tcaswell's example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def emphasize_plot(ax, df, col, **emphargs):
    columns = [c for c in df.columns if c != col]
    df[columns].plot(ax=ax)
    df[col].plot(ax=ax, **emphargs)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
th = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1024)
df = pd.DataFrame({'cos': np.cos(th), 'foobar': np.sin(th),
                  'foo': np.sin(th + 1), 'bar': np.cos(th +1)}, index=th)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'cos': -np.cos(th), 'foobar': -np.sin(th)}, index=th)

emphasize_plot(ax, df, 'foobar', lw=2, c='k')
emphasize_plot(ax, df2, 'foobar', lw=2, c='k')
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used @unutbut's answer and extended it to allow for a secondary y axis and correct legends:

```
def emphasize_plot(ax, df, col, **emphargs):
    columns = [c for c in df.columns if c != col]
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    df[columns].plot(ax=ax)
    df[col].plot(ax=ax2, **emphargs)
    lines, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    lines2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
    ax2.legend(lines + lines2, labels + labels2, loc=0)
```